# How to replace numbers with more user-friendly text in a NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I want the funcionality of a NumericUpdown (cycle through the 12 possible values) but want to display month names rather than 1..12.

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `DomainUpDown` control, which is sort of the same thing as `NumericUpDown`, but for text.

Comment: And DomainUpDown has a "Wrap" property, whereas NumericUpdown does not - so even for numeric stuff it's better!